# How can I use select tag in table

Tags: 8

I create a module that have a table . I create my select tag with this code :

```
$select = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => array(t('0'), t('1'), t('2'), t('3'), t('4'), t('5'), t('6'), t('7'), t('8'), t('9'), t('10')),
);
```

When I use this code in table, select tag not work :

```
$table = [
   '#markup' => '<table><tbody><tr><td>' . $select . '</td></tr></tbody></table>',
];
return $table;
```

The page that show to me :

```
<html><body>
  <table><tbody><tr><td>Array</td></tr></tbody></table>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use for the table the render element [Table](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Render!Element!Table.php/class/Table/8.2.x). There is also an example how to put form elements inside of a table:

```
$form['contacts'] = array(
  '#type' => 'table',
  '#caption' => $this->t('Sample Table'),
  '#header' => array($this->t('Name'), $this->t('Phone')),
);

for ($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++) {
  $form['contacts'][$i]['#attributes'] = array('class' => array('foo', 'baz'));
  $form['contacts'][$i]['name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => $this->t('Name'),
    '#title_display' => 'invisible',
  );

  $form['contacts'][$i]['phone'] = array(
    '#type' => 'tel',
    '#title' => $this->t('Phone'),
    '#title_display' => 'invisible',
  );
}
```